# Getting error while creating foreign key in laravel 5 application

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a Laravel application but while creating foreign keys, I am getting errors. I have 2 tables users and articles I want to connect to tables such that each user will have separate articles.

You can check for more code on https://github.com/Jatinbalodhi96/Laravel-Blogger-Application

```
FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES Persons(user_id)

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`app`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `articles` (`article_id`)) (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (jatin, jatinbalodhi@gmail.com,
```

Migrations:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class AddForeignKeysToArticlesTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('articles', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('article_id', 'articles_ibfk_1')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('articles', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropForeign('articles_ibfk_1');
        });
    }

}
```

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class AddForeignKeysToArticlesTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('articles', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('article_id', 'articles_ibfk_1')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('articles', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropForeign('articles_ibfk_1');
        });
    }

}
```

Stack Trace:

```
    in Connection.php line 673
at Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `articles` (`article_head`, `article_body`) values (?, ?)', array('asdsdad', 'asdcdsdsf'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 629
at Connection->run('insert into `articles` (`article_head`, `article_body`) values (?, ?)', array('asdsdad', 'asdcdsdsf'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 409
at Connection->statement('insert into `articles` (`article_head`, `article_body`) values (?, ?)', array('asdsdad', 'asdcdsdsf')) in Connection.php line 365
at Connection->insert('insert into `articles` (`article_head`, `article_body`) values (?, ?)', array('asdsdad', 'asdcdsdsf')) in Processor.php line 32
at Processor->processInsertGetId(object(Builder), 'insert into `articles` (`article_head`, `article_body`) values (?, ?)', array('asdsdad', 'asdcdsdsf'), 'article_id') in Builder.php line 1963
at Builder->insertGetId(array('article_head' => 'asdsdad', 'article_body' => 'asdcdsdsf'), 'article_id')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'insertGetId'), array(array('article_head' => 'asdsdad', 'article_body' => 'asdcdsdsf'), 'article_id')) in Builder.php line 1337
at Builder->__call('insertGetId', array(array('article_head' => 'asdsdad', 'article_body' => 'asdcdsdsf'), 'article_id')) in Model.php line 1621
at Builder->insertGetId(array('article_head' => 'asdsdad', 'article_body' => 'asdcdsdsf'), 'article_id') in Model.php line 1621
at Model->insertAndSetId(object(Builder), array('article_head' => 'asdsdad', 'article_body' => 'asdcdsdsf')) in Model.php line 1590
at Model->performInsert(object(Builder), array()) in Model.php line 1481
at Model->save() in ArticleEditor.php line 19
at ArticleEditor->insert_Article(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ArticleEditor), 'insert_Article'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 80
at Controller->callAction('insert_Article', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(ArticleEditor), object(Route), 'insert_Article') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(ArticleEditor), object(Route), object(Request), 'insert_Article') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\ArticleEditor', 'insert_Article') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel_apps\Blogger\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: I think your 2016_06_02_100152_add_foreign_keys_to_users_table.php is wrong, it need to add foreign key to `articles` table, not `users` table. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#writing-migrations

Comment: Hey now i had make it right, now foreign key is added to articles, but still getting error while storing data to database.

Comment: Show Your Migrations

Comment: Can you show how you store data?

Comment: i didn't get it "how to store data"?

Comment: How you meet the error, and what error

Comment: i have edited errors on the question

Comment: Are you trying to insert data into articles without giving id ?

Comment: i think yes............

Comment: Add solution in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
$table->foreign('article_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('users')
    ->onUpdate('RESTRICT')
    ->onDelete('RESTRICT');
```

You may enable or disable foreign key constraints within your migrations by using the following :

```
Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you trying to insert without right relation. Mysql will prevent you doing this (cause you define relationship in your last migration)

You should add id to your article.

```
$article = new Article();
$article->id = $userId;  // make sure this id is exist in users table;
// other column you need
$article->save();
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models